# Mongo wont load - Ubuntu 14.04 - PHP5 - Apache2

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, lamp

I have a Digital Ocean droplet where I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, php5, apache2 and the whole LAMP stack. I also installed mongo server and mongo driver for php with help from all the online forums.

1. I did `sudo pecl install mongo` then added `extension=mongo.so` to `php.ini`. i.e, 
   `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and  `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. Then I restarted apache.
2. I then tried `php -m` and I can see mongo module in the list.
3. I tried `php --ini` and I see `20-mongo.ini` in `Additional .ini parsed` list

But for the life of me I cant get it to work. It wont show up in `phpinfo()`. I am trying to run a Codeigniter application where I am loading the mongo library and its failing on this particular line

```
if (!class_exists('Mongo')) {
   $this->_show_error('The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled', 500);
}
```

How do I troubleshoot whats going on?

Details: 
Ubuntu - 14.04.5
Service Provider - Digital Ocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the silliest mistake. I was about to go ahead and delete this question but I thought it might help others who do silly mistakes like me.

I restarted the server like `service apache2 restart`.

What I should've done is `sudo service apache2 restart`.

I know!